# (inter)National A&M Cookie day!

Tags: discussion, community-events, events

### Hereby I declare the 26th of August A&M Cookie day!

As some of you may have noticed in the chat lately, I have been looking into to how to provide the cookies I promised during the election. And after a few failed attempts to bribe some ♦ with cookies, I decided to change my approach. Leading to this event.

[image]

**So how do I get my cookie?**

You can get your cookies by sending the address you would like to receive them on to melloniax@hotmail.com BUT please do make sure to:

- use the following format as title

  - [Username] - Free cookies A&M (not case sensitive)
- Have at-least 150 reputation at the time of sending the email (I will check!)
- Include any preference in cookies in the actual message

  - If no preferences, write a nice pun/joke about cookies
  - If there are any additional requirements for delivery, please note them as well
- Send a mail before 12-sept-2015 (11:59pm gmt+1)

**When will my cookies be delivered?**
This can variate a bit. Depending on how many cookies I will have to send out, I might decided to use another shipping format. Otherwise You can expect them within 14-30 days after the closing of the emails. I will accept the answer on this question when ALL of the cookies have been send out.

**How do I know my email has been received and handled?**
I will try to regularly update a answer to this question with the username's that have signed up and can expect to receive a cookie. I will mark the answer as accepted when I send out all the cookies.

*Note*

All information provided will only be disclosed to me, and me personally. After sending out the cookies, all information regarding addresses will be removed. If you wish for the data to be removed at any time, feel free to contact me through chat, or send another mail with your username and that you wish for it to be removed. If you do not trust me with your address information, do not bother to send a mail for cookies.

**Why (inter)National A&M Cookie day?**
well, no clue. Maybe I will do it again next year? Time will teach.

Comment: Are they freshness-guaranteed even for shipping very far around the world?

Comment: @Killua if mass producers can traffic cookies globally, sometimes taking more then 2 months. Without spoiling them. Yeah Ill manage ;) So Freshness Garuanteed

Comment: what about HoiHoi-san and Taisho. do they get cookies if Hakase and ton.yeung can send an email on their behalf?

Comment: @Memor-X sounds like Death note let x and y question.

Comment: @Memor-X They will get a lovely cookie made of bits and byte's if required so

Comment: How can we send cookies to you?

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ By requesting adresss on the above mentioned mail ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The great list of grand cookie receivers

1. **ALAGAROS** | Recieved at TomoFair
2. **Ankit Sharma** | Packed*
3. **Unihedron** *(your joke was really bad ;P)*- *custom surprise* | Packed*
4. **HamtaroWarrior** *(Chocolate-Chip)* | Packed*

### Phase 1: Baking <s>19-9-2015</s> 26/9/1015

As the end of the sign up is drawing near, I figured posting phase 1 state to be quite appropriate. The baking will start at 19-9-2015, and no worries! I managed to convince my lovely girlfriend to help me bake them *(so they will actually be edible, yay!)* For all those that did not sign up yet or are still deciding, be fast, or miss the lovely super cute cookies!

## Phase 2: Sending them out

As I am currently in the process of packing and sending them out, I figured I should give everybody a little sneak peak of what the are going to receive.
[image]

Now for those that are curious enough to wonder 'why is there a normal cookie along with the chocolate ones?'. Well, that is a lovely surprise :)

All cookies have been send out, please let me know if you did not receive them within 14 days of this update. Otherwise, feel free to edit this post with the message you received them or leave a comment ^^

*contains traces of nuts, and gluten* Does *not* contain *eggs*

Comment: "custom surprise" :O

Comment: ^Deliverys will be slightly delayed due to border clearance issues.

Comment: Boy, can't wait now, you made me hungry..

Comment: @Dimitrimx cough cough.....gun powder .....:D

Comment: I had to privilege to pick mine up at the TomoFair, all I can say is that they tasted great! Thanks again for doing this @Dimitrimx.

Comment: The other cookies will be send out by Monday, I managed to get somebody so far to send them for me ^^.